# Javafx - How to check if a combobox is selected or not

Tags: java

I'm working on a school project, but I'm having a hard time. I need to check if a combobox is selected or not in JavaFX, but I can't find the solution. I hope someone can help me out.

```
if (View.getPriority().getItems().size() <= 0) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setContentText("test");
        alert.show();
```

This is my code. I'm trying to access my combobox from a getter in my View-class.

Comment: Could you share the code ? How do you access the combobox ?

Comment: if you're using an IDE a self explaining name should pop up , like isChecked()

Comment: I just edited my code. I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to it:
`boolean isSelected = !myComboBox.getSelectionModel().isEmpty();`

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen your code, I assume you are looking for `combobox.isShowing()`